# SQL code to remove char from field numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an SQL for use in Excel 2013 macro.
My goal is to return the average of certain numbers based on the value of a related field.

My issue is that some numbers include a > sign at the first char. I have been trying in vain to have SQL detect and ignore the > sign because I need the number to be included in the returned average (cant just toss the instance).

Finally, I cannot alter the data, it must remain intact (even if it's poor data management) per our Admin.

Here is what I have that throws an error:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN data.study = 'studyname' THEN data.result ELSE NULL END)
FROM database data
WHERE data.ID = '12345'
```

When the data does not contain a > (like >10000) there is no problem and it works like a champ. 
When the data contains a > I receive error ORA-01722: invalid number

I attempted to cast the data in the field as a decimal but it throws an error there too:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN data.study = 'studyname' THEN CAST(data.result AS DECIMAL(3, 9) ELSE NULL END)
FROM database data
WHERE data.ID = '12345'
```

This gives me the same error.
I am trying to use the LEFT function to determine if the left-most char is a > but I can't seem to get the syntax down right and the examples online don't pertain to being inside an AVG() function or require me to re-write the data. I've only been using SQL for a week or two now, so it could be something very simple that I'm overlooking.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: You can use some [regexp_replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) functionality for this. Something like `CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(data.result, '[^0-9.]', '') as Decimal(3, 9))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the LEFT function is LEFT([column name], number of characters).

You can try

> AVG(CAST(DECODE(LEFT([your column], 1), '>', SUBSTR([your column], 2, len([your_column]), [your_column]) AS DECIMAL(3,9)))

DECODE provides conditional logic. So if the first character is a > then use everything except the first character, otherwise use the whole thing.

Or use the REPLACE function.

> AVG(CAST (REPLACE([your column], '>', '') AS DECIMAL(3,9)))

Comment: Thank you Sam. Both examples throw different errors, but they're so close!
The top query I get the error ORA-00904 "LEFT" invalid identifier. I checked my code and it's referring to tables and fields appropriately. One detail I did notice was that DECODE did not change color, could it be that its not supported?

The second query returns ORA-01438 value larger than specified precision allowed for this column. Is this because Its stored as Charvar2? Is there a way cast it as a different variable type without creating a new column?

Thank you again!

Comment: You might be getting ORA-01438 if your values are bigger than decimal(3,9) in the underlying source strings. How big is the largest number in your table, left and right of the decimal place?

Comment: I changed it to DOUBLE PRECISION and I got a bad number error (same as above). Upon further data scouring (over 40000 records) I discovered a single typo where '>' was '<' (anger and rage followed). I nested a second REPLACE for the '<' and it works like a charm! Thank you everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the value is a valid number.  This is probably good enough for your purpose:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN data.study = 'studyname' AND
                     REGEXP_LIKE(data.result, '^[0-9]{0-3}[.]?[0-9]{0-9}$')
                THEN CAST(data.result AS DECIMAL(3, 9) 
           END)
FROM database data
WHERE data.ID = '12345'
```

Comment: Plugged this in, the data came back null. How do I interpret?

Comment: @St.Jimmy .  . . That would suggest that `data.result` does not look like a number.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check/change the column format in excel from general to Number format and try.

General format may give you exponent values that may cause the error.

I hope this might help.